# Reading filename using regexp in Bash

Tags: bash, 7zip

I am writing a bash script that calls an external program which generates a zip file of the form ########.zip which the '#'s# can be any decimal digit.  There is no way to predict what the digits will be.

So far I have been able to get by using the regexp [0-9][0-9]*zip for things like moving the zip file around and unzipping it.  However, now I need to add a txt file to the archive under the directory name ######## where the digits are the same as the archive name.  So, if the archive is 12345678.zip, I need to add the file 12345678/foo.txt.

The only way I can see to do this is to create the directory '12345678' and copy the file there and then add the directory to the archive.  However I can't figure out how to get the name of the archive so that I can create the directory.

The best I could some up with was to use backticks to assign the output of ls -l to a variable and then parse that to get just the filename part.  But there has to be an easier way?

I am using 7z as the zip utility if it matters.

Thanks!

Comment: Do not try to parse `ls` -- see [ParsingLs](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Comment: `[0-9][0-9]*zip` in a shell is not a regex, it's a glob expression.

Comment: ...beyond that, it's hard to tell what you're trying to do. Could you set up a [mre] -- a small script that creates a directory structure and then attempts to perform your desired operation inside it, with a clear description of how its actual and intended behaviors differ?

Comment: BTW, presuming you know 7z usage, I'll let you adjust the answer (which is written with the standard UNIX zip tool) to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're asking for is not a regex but a "glob expression". In particular, if you want to match any number of digits, this can be done with a bash feature called extended globbing, or "extglobs". Read more at https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pattern#extended_pattern_language.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
#              ^^^^- NOT sh

shopt -s extglob
for f in +([[:digit:]]).zip; do
  digits=${f%.zip}
  mkdir -p "$digits"
  echo hello >"$digits/foo.txt"
  zip "$f" "$digits/foo.txt"
done
```

In the [parameter expansion](https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe) `digits=${f%.zip}`, we take `.zip` off the end of the filename, and store the rest in the variable `digits`.

---

Extending the above to work in a temporary directory and clean up after ourselves:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
#              ^^^^- NOT sh

shopt -s extglob
olddir=$PWD
for f in +([[:digit:]]).zip; do
  digits=${f%.zip}
  tempdir="$(mktemp -d -t zipupdate.XXXXXX)"
  (
    cd "$tempdir" || exit
    mkdir -p "$digits" || exit
    echo hello >"$digits/foo.txt" || exit
    zip "$olddir/$f" "$digits/foo.txt"
  )
  rm -rf "$tempdir"
done
```

Comment: This worked great, though it's all entirely new to me.  I'll have to research a bit to understand it all.  Anyway, I really appreciate the help.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Since OP is using `7z` we can make use of the `rn` option to rename a file within the archive *and* eliminate the need to create/delete a temporary subdirectory ...

Setup:

```
$ 'rm' -rf zipdir
$ mkdir zipdir
$ cd zipdir

$ zipfile='12345678.zip'
$ digits="${zipfile//.zip/}"
$ declare -p digits
declare -- digits="12345678"

$ echo abc > sample.txt
$ echo def > foo.txt
```

Create/populate `${zipfile}` with `sample.txt` and `foo.txt`:

```
$ 7z a "${zipfile}" sample.txt foo.txt
... snip ...
Archive size: 158 bytes (1 KiB)
Everything is Ok

$ 7z l "${zipfile}"
... snip ...
   Date      Time    Attr         Size   Compressed  Name
------------------- ----- ------------ ------------  ------------------------
2022-05-14 15:53:16 .....            4            4  foo.txt
2022-05-14 15:53:16 .....            4            4  sample.txt
------------------- ----- ------------ ------------  ------------------------
2022-05-14 15:53:16                  8            8  2 files
```

Now add the `${digits}` directory as a prefix to `foo.txt`:

```
$ 7z -- rn "${zipfile}" foo.txt "${digits}/foo.txt"
... snip ...
Archive size: 306 bytes (1 KiB)
Everything is Ok

$ 7z l "${zipfile}"
... snip ...
   Date      Time    Attr         Size   Compressed  Name
------------------- ----- ------------ ------------  ------------------------
2022-05-14 15:53:16 .....            4            4  12345678/foo.txt
2022-05-14 15:53:16 .....            4            4  sample.txt
------------------- ----- ------------ ------------  ------------------------
2022-05-14 15:53:16                  8            8  2 files
```

Comment: That's pretty slick.  Thanks!